# Is it possible to significantly reduce the inference time of images by reducing the number of object classes?

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am using YOLOv4 to train my custom detector. Source: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

One of the issues while training is the computing power of GPU and available video RAM. What is the relationship between number of object classes and the time it takes to train the model? Also, is it possible to significantly reduce the inference time of images by reducing the number of object classes? The goal is to run inference on a Raspberry Pi or a Jetson Nano.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The less classes, the easier to train in general. I am not sure how darknet works, if it uses more layers when there are more classes. Or do you choose the amount of layers? If so, try less layers with less classes. And less layers mean faster model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I know, we can choose layers. I am using YOLO tiny which has 38 layers as opposed to standard YOLO which has around 110 layers. I have 8 classes. I feel the results are not as good as I want. I may go for a standard YOLO training.

Comment: Reducing the number of classes effects the computations in prediction (YOLO) layers only. Computationally, other layers remain the same only. It is not at all significant when you consider a dense model like YOLOv4. 

You can also Tiny-YOLOv4 where the processing power is limited (Jetson Nano, rasp pi, etc.) and you want a lighter model.

Answer (score 2):

> Change is number of classes doesn't have significant impact on
> inference time.

For example in case of [Yolov4](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4.cfg), which has got 3 `Yolo` layers, change in classes leads to change in **`filter size`** for `conv` layers preceding `Yolo` layers and some computation reduction within `Yolo` layers that's all. This is very minute compared to overall inference time as `conv` layers preceding `Yolo` layers are bottom layers with very small width and hight and also time spent on logic that depends upon number of classes within [Yolo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/src/region_layer.c) layer is very less.

[image: Snapshot of Yolo layer]

Here:

```
filters=(classes + 5)x3
```

Note that tinier version of yolov4 i.e [tiny-yolov4](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov4-tiny.cfg) have got two `Yolo` layers only, instead of 3.

**If your intent is to reduce inference time, especially on raspberry pi or a jetson nano, without losing on accuracy/mAP, do following things:**

- **Quantisation**: Run inference with `INT8` instead of `FP32`. You can use this [repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/yolo2_light) for this purpose. You can do this for both Jetson nano and raspberry pi.
- Use inference library such as [**tkDNN**](https://github.com/ceccocats/tkDNN), which is a Deep Neural Network library built with `cuDNN` and `tensorRT` primitives, specifically thought to work on **NVIDIA Jetson** Boards. You can use this for Jetson nano. Note that with [**TensorRT**](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt), you can use `INT8` and `FP16` instead of `FP32` to reduce detection time.

**Following techniques can be used to reduce inference time, but they come at the cost of significant drop in accuracy/mAP:**

- You can train the models with tinier versions rather than full Yolo versions.
- Model Pruning - If you could rank the neurons in the network according to how much they contribute, you could then remove the low ranking neurons from the network, resulting in a smaller and faster network. Pruned yolov3 research [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.11093v1) and it's [implementation](https://github.com/PengyiZhang/SlimYOLOv3). [This](https://github.com/Lam1360/YOLOv3-model-pruning) is another pruned Yolov3 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reducing the number of classes from 80 to 5 classes, I was aiming to detect vehicles only, on YOLOv3 and found a reduction in time. For example, using Intel Core i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40 GHz, the time was reduced by 50%, and for Nvidia GeForce 930M, it was reduced by 20%. Generally, the stronger the processor, the less reduction in time you get.